# ModelMapper Calculations

Tags: java, modelmapper

I am trying to use `ModelMapper` to calculate properties during the mapping process. Is this possible as it's not working as I'd expect.

```
PropertyMap<com.fmg.myfluent.domain.Quote, ClientQuote> personMap = new     
    PropertyMap<com.fmg.myfluent.domain.Quote, ClientQuote>() {
       protected void configure() {
          map().setTotalLoan(source.getTotalPayable());
          // monthlyRate NOT Working!
          map().setMonthlyRate((source.getAnnualRate()/12));
       }
    };
```

I am expecting Month Rate to be Annual Rate / 12. However, Monthly Rate is set to Annual Rate without the calculation.

Expect:

```
 Annual Rate = 12, Monthly Rate: 1
```

Actual:

`Annual Rate = 12, Monthly Rate: 12`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a manual converter to convert a value in `ModelMapper`

```
Converter<Integer, Integer> annualToMonthlyConverter = ctx -> ctx.getSource() == 0 ? 0 : ctx.getSource() / 12;
```

Now use this converter to convert your source annual field to you target monthly field

```
PropertyMap<Source, Target> personMap = new
            PropertyMap<Source, Target>() {
                protected void configure() {
                    map().setAnnual(source.getAnnual());

                    using(annualToMonthlyConverter).map(source.getAnnual(), destination.getMonthly());
                }
            };
```

**Note:**

Just an idea, according to your design, you could also only map source's annual field and then return `annual/12` from your target class's `monthly`'s getter

```
public int getMonthly() {
    return annual / 12;
}
```

Comment: Thanx Debmalya, this is what I was looking for. I'd tried "using" the Converter but forgot/missed the map!

Comment: I am glad it helped. Please accept the answer if you feel this is helpful. Thanks